# Is it Possible to include MQL5 standard library in MQL4 Platform?

Tags: shared-libraries, standards, mql4, mql5

I am trying to include MQL5 standard library in my MQL4 developing platform but with no success so far.. I have just copied the include file from MQL5 platform into an include File of an MQL4 Platform but the libraries are not recognized..

not sure where i am going wrong

```
// 
#include <Trade\PositionInfo.mqh>//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
class Position : public CPositionInfo  
  {
  
CPositionInfo cPositionInfo;
```

it says CPosition declaration without a type

Comment: No. The underlying API functions are totally different so MQL5 classes won't work on MQL4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to copy the sources of Include from MQL5 folder to MQL4, it compiles ok quite often but it may require you some efforts if you apply MQL5/Include/Math library and some others.
There are two libraries that you cannot include into MQL4. They are MQL5\Include\Trade and \OpenCL. The latter is not supported in MQL4, the first one is very different in MQL4.
You are trying to extend from Include\Trade\PositionInfo.mqh that is part of Trade library. If you go through that file, you will see it cannot be compiled at MQL4 editor because some functions and constants are not declared.

Comment: All of the standard library classes that are cross-platform compatible already come shipped with MT4. Metaquotes just released the June update for MT4 which includes enhancements for Meta-editor/STL. The platform and editor build numbers are `1126` and `1861` respectively. You can upgrade by logging into the metaquotes demo or I also made a handy package for installing a vanilla version of MT4 and included a script to install terminals in portable mode, clone, and symlink...   https://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?t=803172

Comment: I told that some libraries are not cross platform, but can be compiled at MT4 with some modifications. Some libraries cannot be compiled because of MT4 to MT5 difference. MT4 docs say the latest platform is `1090`, MT5 has `1880(or 1881)` so it is not clear what you mean when telling about build `1861`

Comment: You are right, but that is not an official version, just beta